# More efficient way to get unique first occurrence from a Python dict

Tags: python, maps, unique, dictionary

I have  a very large file I'm parsing and getting the key value from the line. I want only the first key and value, for only one value. That is, I'm removing the duplicate values

So it would look like:

```
{
A:1
B:2
C:3
D:2
E:2
F:3
G:1
}
```

and it would output:

```
{E:2,F:3,G:1}
```

It's a bit confusing because I don't really care what the key is. So E in the above could be replaced with B or D, F could be replaced with C, and G could be replaced with A.

Here is the best way I have found to do it but it is extremely slow as the file gets larger.

```
mapp = {}
value_holder = []

for i in mydict:
 if mydict[i] not in value_holder:
   mapp[i] = mydict[i]
   value_holder.append(mydict[i])
```

Must look through value_holder every time :( Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: You're question is extremely difficult to read and understand. Please clarify and give a better idea of the data you're working with.

Comment: So, in the case where multiple keys have the same value, do you care which key is the one that is kept?  Or is it guaranteed that each value is always paired with the same key?  Or do you want the first key that appeared in the very large file?

Comment: No i don't care which key is kept :)

Comment: Made the question much more clear.

Comment: One last thing: Your examples are all `int` values, which are hashable, sortable, and almost-anything-else-able. Can you rely on the values being hashable in your real code?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I shouldn't of chosen ints as they are actually very long strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a trivial change makes it much faster:

```
value_holder = set()
```

(Well, you also have to change the `append` to `add`. But still pretty simple.)

Using a set instead of a list means each lookup is O(1) instead of O(N), so the whole operation is O(N) instead of O(N^2). In other words, if you have 10,000 lines, you're doing 10,000 hash lookups instead of 50,000,000 comparisons.

One caveat with this solution—and all of the others posted—is that it requires the values to be hashable. If they're not hashable, but they are comparable, you can still get O(NlogN) instead of O(N^2) by using a sorted set (e.g., from the [`blist`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) library). If they're neither hashable nor sortable… well, you'll probably want to find some way to generate something hashable (or sortable) to use as a "first check", and then only walk the "first check" matches for actual matches, which will get you to O(NM), where M is the average number of hash collisions.

You might want to look at how `unique_everseen` is implemented in the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) in the standard library documentation.

Note that dictionaries don't actually have an order, so there's no way to pick the "first" duplicate; you'll just get one arbitrarily. In which case, there's another way to do this:

```
inverted = {v:k for k, v in d.iteritems()}
reverted = {v:k for k, v in inverted.iteritems()}
```

(This is effectively a form of the [decorate-process-undecorate](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#The_Old_Way_Using_Decorate-Sort-Undecorate) idiom without any processing.)

But instead of building up the `dict` and then filtering it, you can make things better (simpler, and faster, and more memory-efficient, and order-preserving) by filtering as you read. Basically, keep the `set` alongside the `dict` as you go along. For example, instead of this:

```
mydict = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.split(None, 1)
    mydict[k] = v

mapp = {}
value_holder = set()

for i in mydict:
    if mydict[i] not in value_holder:
        mapp[i] = mydict[i]
        value_holder.add(mydict[i])
```

Just do this:

```
mapp = {}
value_holder = set()
for line in f:
    k, v = line.split(None, 1)
    if v not in value_holder:
        mapp[k] = v
        value_holder.add(v)
```

In fact, you may want to consider writing a `one_to_one_dict` that wraps this up (or search PyPI modules and ActiveState recipes to see if someone has already written it for you), so then you can just write:

```
mapp = one_to_one_dict()
for line in f:
    k, v = line.split(None, 1)
    mapp[k] = v
```

Comment: I like this. I actually came up with the inverted dict on my own, and it works great. Thanks for the great explanations!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely clear on exactly what you're doing, but `set` is a great way to remove duplicates.  For example:

```
>>> k = [1,3,4,4,5,4,3,2,2,3,3,4,5]
>>> set(k)
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> list(set(k))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Though it depends a bit on the structure of the input that you're loading, there might be a way to simply use `set` so that you don't have to iterate through the entire object every time to see if there any matching keys--instead run it through `set` once.

Answer (score 2):

The first way to speed this up, as others have mentioned, is a using a `set` to record seen values, as checking for membership on a set is much faster.

We can also make this a lot shorter with a [dict comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
seen = set()
new_mapp = {k: v for k, v in mapp.items() if v not in seen or seen.add(i)}
```

The if case requires a little explanation: we only add key/value pairs where we havn't seen the value before, but we use `or` a little bit hackishly to ensure any unseen values are added to the set. As `set.add()` returns `None`, it will not affect the outcome.

As always, in 2.x, user `dict.iteritems()` over `dict.items()`.

Comment: Calling a function for its side effects in the `if` clause of a comprehension is not exactly pythonic. Shorter is not always better. As for performance, there's a long discussion on python-ideas, and at least one post on SO, where different implementations of `unique_everseen` are compared, and this is not the fastest.

Comment: @abarnert You are right - putting the add in the `if` clause is fairly hacky - it's probably not the best option. That said, I would argue it isn't a terrible answer - so the -1 is a little harsh.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, and in fact I think it was already at +1/-1 before I wrote my comment, so I don't even know if this is the reason it was downvoted. I think the "a little better" wording is misleading, but not -1 misleading. It's also possible you got downvoted for asserting that it's faster without evidence—I've been downvoted without comment even in cases where I'm just pasting in the fastest solution from a linked list thread/SO answer/whatever…

Comment: Ah, apologies for making the assumption - bleh to the other guy that didn't give a reason. I'll remove the speed comment anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `set` instead of a `list` would speed you up considerably ...

Answer (score -1):

You said you are reading from a very large file and want to keep only the first occurrence of a key.  I originally assumed this meant you care about the order in which the key/value pairs occurs in the very large file. This code will do that and will be fast.

```
values_seen = set()
mapp = {}
with open("large_file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        if value not in values_seen:
            values_seen.add(value)
            mapp[key] = value
```

You were using a `list` to keep track of what keys your code had seen.  Searching through a `list` is very slow: it gets slower the larger the list gets.  A `set` is much faster because lookups are close to constant time (don't get much slower, or maybe at all slower, the larger the list gets).  (A `dict` also works the way a `set` works.)

Comment: This removes duplicate keys, not values. And since you can't have duplicate keys in a `dict` in the first place, it has no effect.

Comment: @abarnert, fair enough.  I'll edit the code to ignore keys and check only values.

Answer (score -1):

Part of your problem is that dicts do not preserve any sort of logical ordering when they are iterated through.  They use hash tables to index items (see [this great article](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/)).  So there's no real concept of "first occurence of value" in this sort of data structure.  The right way to do this would probably be a list of key-value pairs.  e.g. :

```
kv_pairs = [(k1,v1),(k2,v2),...]
```

or, because the file is so large, it would be better to use the excellent file iteration python provides to retrieve the k/v pairs:

```
def kv_iter(f):
    # f being the file descriptor
    for line in f:
        yield ... # (whatever logic you use to get k, v values from a line)
```

Value_holder is a great candidate for a set variable.  You are really just testing whether value_holder.  Because values are unique, they can be indexed more efficiently using a similar hashing method.  So it would end up a bit like this:

```
mapp = {}
value_holder = set()

for k,v in kv_iter(f):
    if v in value_holder:
       mapp[k] = v
       value_holder.add(v)
```

Comment: Why would you fake a `set` with a `dict`? Unless you need Python 2.1 compatibility, this just makes things more complicated for no reason.

Comment: I didn't realize that sets were optimized for testing the presence of values.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what you mean by "optimized", but a `set` uses effectively the same hash table as a `dict`. (In fact, the 2.2 implementation was just a `dict` mapping each key to `None` under the covers.) There are minor performance differences—apparently in 3.1-3.3, `set` is often a little slower in 32-bit builds and a little faster in 64-bit builds—but unless that tiny difference matters, the benefits in simplicity (not to mention half the memory usage) win.